# Can Pantheon Files show sub-menus?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, context-menu

In Nautilus, menus and sub-menus are editable with `nautilus-actions-config-tool`,

[image]

Which gives:

[image]

in Pantheon Files by manually editing `contract` files (added to `~/.local/share/contractor`).

Are these `.contract` files editable so that to add sub-menus to the Pantheon Files manager's context menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can add submenus with plugins (e.g. the dropbox plugin) but I do not think you can with contracts which are essentially app launchers.

Comment: I am not talking about a specific plugin like that for Dropbox (by the way: is there one for Pantheon Files?) but about something close to what happens in other file managers.  Dolphin and Nautilus allow context menu options/actions (which are also "apps launchers') that can be structured in sub-levels of menus. But while Nautilus does it through some gsettings, Dolphin in Plasma5 does it with files that can be manually edited to create  multi-level menus, and these files are desktop files in `~/.local/share/kservices5`. - I was just wandering if contract files syntax supports that.

Comment: Then the answer is no.  In principle it might be possible to create a plugin that gave that functionality but there are no plans to do so at the moment.  You could always create a wishlist report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files but in general Elementary does not like users to mess about with the UI.

Comment: please add that in your answer to be clear that the answer is NO (while removing the dropbox info) and I will mark this as definitive